# Rails returns a weird string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

could anyone tell me why does my rails application returns this piece of code when I do a select statement?

```
#<Driver:0x22ef3f0>
```

The select statement is:

```
current_schedule_record = {
  'driver_name' => Driver.where(['id = ?', id]).select('first_name').first
}
```

and the view is:

```
<% @trucks.each do |truck| %>
  <% record = ScheduleController.schedule_record(truck.id) %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= truck.id %></td>
            <td><%= record['driver_name'] %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)

> Be careful because this also means you're initializing a model object with only the fields that you've selected.

So using select still creates a model object. You need to use something like

```
current_schedule_record = {
  'driver_name' => Driver.where(['id = ?', id]).select('first_name').first.first_name
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why I have to add first_name at the end.  I thought that the .select('first_name') will tell it what to select.  Any chance you could clarify this for me? I marked your answer as correct and thank you for that link, it is going to prove to be very helpful to me.

Comment: @Bagzli ActiveRecord always returns a collection of Models regardless of whether or not you specify which columns to select, have a look at the documentation again.